# Limit landscape to a specific page, jquery mobile, iOS, phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm using the following code to detect orientation changes:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

 function doOnOrientationChange()
    {
        switch(window.orientation)
      {
        case -90:
        case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break;
        default:
        alert('portrait');
        break;
     }
}
```

How do I prevent the orientation change on certain pages in jqm? Seems if I can detect the change I can prevent the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only certain web views / UI contexts to respond to orientation you need to do this in the native layer. Otherwise your stuff will just follow a responsive layout.